# expandableListView working fine only for 4 items in the list and not showing the child elements after that

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

My listData has over 10 elements but the data for the first 4 is only showing properly and the rest is not showing the child data

do i need to use notifyDataSetChanged() ?

I tried to use it but it did not work

Please assist

The code for MainActivity and Adapter is provided below..

```
package com.android.kiddo.restaurantorderapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Dhaval on 24-02-2016.
 */
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.kiddo.restaurantorderapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;;
    Button checkout_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkout_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Paratha");
        listDataHeader.add("Sabzee");
        listDataHeader.add("Rice");
        listDataHeader.add("Starters");
        listDataHeader.add("Pizza");
        listDataHeader.add("Burger");
        listDataHeader.add("Pasta");
        listDataHeader.add("Chinese");
        listDataHeader.add("South Indian");
        listDataHeader.add("Sweets");
        listDataHeader.add("Deserts");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> paratha = new ArrayList<String>();
        paratha.add("Methi");
        paratha.add("Gobi");
        paratha.add("Paneer");

        List<String> sabzee = new ArrayList<String>();
        sabzee.add("Paneer Tikka Masala");
        sabzee.add("Palak Paneer");
        sabzee.add("Methi Mutter");


        List<String> rice = new ArrayList<String>();
        rice.add("Biryani");
        rice.add("Pulav");
        rice.add("Fried Rice");
        rice.add("Jeera Rice");
        rice.add("Plain");

        List<String> starters = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> pizza = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> burger = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> pasta = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> chinese = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> south = new ArrayList<String>();
        starters.add("Biryani");
        starters.add("Pulav");
        starters.add("Fried Rice");
        starters.add("Jeera Rice");
        starters.add("Plain");

        List<String> sweets = new ArrayList<String>();
        paratha.add("Methi");
        paratha.add("Gobi");
        paratha.add("Paneer");

        List<String> deserts = new ArrayList<String>();
        sabzee.add("Paneer Tikka Masala");
        sabzee.add("Palak Paneer");
        sabzee.add("Methi Mutter");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), paratha); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), sabzee);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), rice);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3),starters);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4),pizza);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5),burger);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6),pasta);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), chinese);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(8), south);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(9), sweets);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(10),deserts);

    }

    public void checkout(View view) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkout"
        android:onClick="checkout"
        android:background="#060404"
        android:textColor="#ffea00"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

List_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#ffea00" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textColor="#ffea00"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please assist ..

Comment: I have added the xml codes also..

Comment: visit this link you have easily made ExpandableListView http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I have used that same code but when I am adding new groups , it is giving  not populating the child views

Comment: I have use that and work check the code again ?